# How to debug "A non-numeric value encountered" in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling, numeric

I am getting this PHP return error in my BookinginfoController.php line 101:

> A non-numeric value encountered...

Here's the some of the script. Please explain in basic terms here.

```
$token =csrf_token();
       $idmy = Auth::user()->id;

       $bookingget = DB::table('booking')

               ->where('user_id', '=', $idmy)
                ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
                ->where('token', '=', $token)
               ->orderBy('book_id','desc')
                ->get();

                $neshopp = $bookingget[0]->shop_id;

       $shopnewie = DB::table('shop')
         ->where('id', '=', $neshopp)
         ->get();

         $id = $shopnewie[0]->user_id;



       $userdetails = DB::table('users')
         ->where('id', '=', $id)
         ->get();

        $booking = DB::table('booking')
               ->where('token', '=', $token)
               ->where('status', '=', 'pending')
               ->where('user_id', '=', $idmy)
               ->orderBy('book_id','desc')
                ->get();


        $ser_id=$booking[0]->services_id;
            $sel=explode("," , $ser_id);
            $lev=count($sel);
            $ser_name="";
            $sum="";
            $price="";

        for($i=0;$i<$lev;$i++)
            {
                $id=$sel[$i];   



                $fet1 = DB::table('subservices')
                                 ->where('subid', '=', $id)
                                 ->get();
                $ser_name.=$fet1[0]->subname.'<br>';
                $ser_name.=",";              



                $fet2 = DB::table('seller_services')
                                 ->where('subservice_id', '=', $id)
                                 ->where('shop_id', '=', $neshopp)
                                 ->get();
                $price.=$fet2[0]->price.'<br>';
                $price.=",";    




                $ser_name=trim($ser_name,",");
                $price=trim($price,",");    
                $sum+=$fet2[0]->price;
```

I'm using PHP 7.2

Line 99, 100, 101, is

```
$ser_name=trim($ser_name,",");

 $price=trim($price,",");   

$sum+=$fet2[0]->price;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on php 7.1+, this is caused because you initialize the `$sum` variable as an emtpy string:

```
$sum = '';
```

Instead, you should initialize it as a number:

```
$sum = 0;
```

See [an example](https://3v4l.org/4oeVj).

Obviously, `$fet2[0]->price` needs to be numeric, but if it is a string, php will cast it without warnings.